# Resolving polygon self intersection faster than O($n^2$)

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Given a 2D polygon represented by an ordered sequence of points on a plane. Polygon can be only closed, and have self intersections.

I am looking for algorithm that resolving self intersections of this polygon faster than O($n^2$).

I have tried to separate the part of Vatti clipping algorithm, that resolving self intersections, but failed.
The correct result is something like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably know that simplicity can be tested in O(*n*) time via Chazelle's algorithm, but it is so complicated that no one implements it.
Simpler implementations without the same asymptotic time-complexity are
much preferable. For example:

> Feito, F., Juan Carlos Torres, and A. Urena. "Orientation, simplicity, and inclusion test for planar polygons." *Computers & Graphics* 19.4 (1995): 595-600.
>   ([PDF download](http://hera.ugr.es/doi/15026760.pdf).)

If you really want good asymptotic time-complexity, you can easily achieve
O(*n* log *n*) through Shamos & Hoey's algorithm. See, e.g., [Dan Sunday's explanation](http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. But i haven't problems with test simplicity of polygon. I have a problems with resolving intersections in polygon, and make it simple.

Comment: @МаксимМолчанов: Then you need to explain what "resolving intersections" means, and "making it simple." There could be many interpretations of these phrases.

Comment: @JosephORourke "resolve intersection" means insert 2 points in polygon, in the **correct place**,and move them far away from each other